# Simple IAM Issue with CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I'm having an issue with a seemingly trivial task of getting CodeDeploy to deploy Github code to an AutoScaling Group in a Blue/Green Deployment.

I have a Pipeline setup, a Deployment Group setup, and the AutoScaling Group, but it fails when it gets to the actual deployment:

[image]

---

I went to my role and it seems like it has sufficient policies for it to go through with the blue/green deployment:

[image]

---

Is there a policy that I'm not considering that needs to be attached to this role?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was also getting the error:

"The IAM role does not give you permission to perform operations in the following AWS service: AmazonAutoScaling. Contact your AWS administrator if you need help. If you are an AWS administrator, you can grant permissions to your users or groups by creating IAM policies."

I figured out the 2 permissions needed to get past this error, I created the policy below and attached it to the Code Deploy role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I copypasted the provided role and still have the same error.

Comment: I have the same issue as @Defozo

Comment: Hey @Defozo you can find more details here. The problem happening because (I assume) you created your ASG using Launch Template instead of Launch Config:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html

Comment: added CreateTags, I didn't need it when I first ran into this issue, perhaps the issue I had was slightly different, or that the new permission is now needed?

Answer (score 25):

I found the answer in this link:
https://h2ik.co/2019/02/28/aws-codedeploy-blue-green/

Without wanting to take the credit, only one statement was missing from @PeskyGnat :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it secure to use "Resource": "*" ?

Comment: No. BUT you are giving this to a trusted service in aws

Answer (score 0):

After conducting some research, I found that the following IAM policy has worked for me:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "sts:GetCallerIdentity",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "sqs:ListQueues",
                "ec2:DescribeSpotPriceHistory"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
```